# Programatically differentiate between facebook pages and profiles

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm writing an app which requires me to determine whether I show the fb "like" button or not. fb profiles don't have "likes" but pages do. any recommendations on how I can programatically differentiate between a fb profile and a fb page? the only input i get from the user is the fb profile/page URL and based on that I need to determine whether its a page or a profile and then display the like button.

thx,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can look at the type attribute of the returned JSON.  For example, take a look at actual, redacted Graph API responses that I receive for a user and a page:

```
//This is JSON for a user
//Call to https://graph.facebook.com/123456789
{
  "id": "123456789", 
  "name": "Sean Hill", 
  "first_name": "Sean", 
  "last_name": "Hill",
  //more attributes
  "type": "user"  // <--- This one
}
```

vs

```
//This is JSON for a page
//Call to https://graph.facebook.com/thesolusean
{
  "id": "323796444951", 
  "name": "Solusean", 
  "picture": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/50290_323796444951_3601170_s.jpg", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/thesolusean", 
  "likes": 28,
  // more attributes
  "type": "page"  // <---- This one
}
```

Without knowing which programming language you're using, this is the best answer I can give.

Answer (score 0):

So far it seems the only quick way to know whether given profile is page or actual user is by looking at category attribute. If this attribute is present then its a page otherwise it could be user. FB reference docs doesn't seem to have any clear guidance (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/profile). In additional most of the APIs that return profile as part of other response only includes partial information of id, name and category:

```
  "from": {
    "category": "Magazine", 
    "name": "Astronomy Magazine", 
    "id": "108218329601"
  },
```

Note: I'm confused by @Sean Hill's answer. There is no type attribute in profile objects.